# Magento1.9 Where is frontend design defined if it's not defined in Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, multi-website

I'm working on a Magento 1.9 project, which has 4 different websites.

Each website is using it's own design.

Inside this path **public/app/design/frontend/default/**, there are different folders (english, german, norwegian, swedish) that are used as design to different website.

And normally we can define which theme a storeview should be using in *Admin->System->Design*. But this area is empty for this project. So I wonder where else it is defined for these themes, so each website knows which design it should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in this path. Here we can configure the package and related themes for each store view.

**System > configuration > design**

Comment: ah.. you are right, it is defined under System->configuration->design. Do you know what's the different between this path and Admin->system->design?

Comment: 1. System > design is used to set theme for a specific time period. Let's say you want a special theme for a festival. You can set it under that along with from and to dates.Theme will expire automatically and switch to the default theme set under system>configuration>design 2. Whereas system > configuration > design is to set a permanent theme. This is standard way to set a theme.